# Making a class with classes within it

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I need to store data so I have; restaurantName, categories for that restaurant(which would be an array of Strings), an array of Items for each category, and a number for each item in the array. Heres what I have

```
open class Item{
var name = String()
var numberOfCarbs = Int()
var category = String()
init(name n:String,numberOfCarbs c:Int,category t:String){
    name = n
    numberOfCarbs = c
    category = t
}

}
open class Restaurant{

var items = [Item]()
var cateogry = [String]()
var restaurantName = String()

init(restaurantName n:String,category c:[String],items i:[Item]){
    restaurantName = n
    cateogry = c
    items = i
}
```

I don't think that this is the best way to do this, can someone tell me how to structure this.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Separating the name from the numberOfCarbs @rmaddy

Comment: That does't clarify anything because the code you posted already does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have an array of items for each category. If that is the case then a category shouldn't be an array of Strings, it should be an array of Categories.

```
struct Item {
    let name: String 
    let carbs: Int
}

struct Category {
    let name: String
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Restaurant {
    let name: String 
    let categories: [Category]
}
```

-- Edit in answer to question in comments --

```
let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)

let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [])
let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

let a_w = Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])

let menuArray = [a_w]
```

Comment: sorry for all the questions but I did this `let currentRestaurant = menuArray[indexPath.row]
currentCell?.textLabel!.text = currentRestaurant.name` and nothing shows up in the table view for name @DanielT.